# Blender 2.8 Array Circle along plane

Tags: python, modifiers

I still have no good solution on how to create an array modifier for an object to

1) Rotate in a circle (I know it can be done with an empty that is rotated) but... (see 2)

2) The objects should keep a certain rotation along a plane like this:

[image]

So for example where the 3d cursor is there could be an empty with the same rotation as the cube...

... then rotate the empty around the local z axis... will work.

The only thing is now: Let's assume that I have 10 array items. What is the exact rotation of the empty (x, y, z) to create a perfect circle? Because I want to define this programmatically with Python.

Comment: If the plane is going to be the starting point, I'd create the array around the Z-axis (with X and Y at 0 deg.), then rotate the array and the empty together according to the plane's rotation.

Comment: @metaphor_set: Ok, and how do you get the rotation of the plane with Python?

Comment: I never dived that much into the Blender Python api, my comment was more of a hint how I'd solve this without having to deal with the rotation of the array duplicates.

Comment: @metaphor_set : ah ok, but I found it. I am rotaing the empty now for the local Z axis like this: circle_empty.rotation_euler.rotate_axis("Z", radians(angle)) - I will add the functionality in 1-2 days to my Fast Carve addon.

Answer (score 1):

Answer found:

You can set the local Z-axis rotation for the empty object like this:

```
empty_obj.rotation_euler.rotate_axis("Z", radians(angle))
```